# 64-bit DB2 10.5 missing 32-bit libpam and 64-bit libaio on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, software-installation, database

This happened to me. If it's happening to you, maybe this can save you
a bit of time.

I was installing 64-bit DB2 10.5 server (not sure exactly what product package
-- someone gave it to me) on a SoftLayer 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 Linux system that
included a LAMP stack.

Bottom line first: It turns out that I was missing 32-bit libpam and 64-bit
libaio and needed to do:

```
   apt-get install libpam0g:i386 libaio1
```

Most folks' mileage will undoubtedly vary. In case only part of the experience
applies to you, and would be helpful for you, here is more detail.

Before the install, `db2prereqcheck` complained:

```
   DBT3514W  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following
   32-bit library file: "/lib/libpam.so*".
```

Sure enough, all I had was:

```
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.0
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpamc.so.0
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpamc.so.0.82.1
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0
```

After looking around the web a bit, I did:

```
   apt-get install libpam0g:i386
```

after which I also had:

```
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.0
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpamc.so.0
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpamc.so.0.82.1
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam_misc.so.0
```

But db2prereqcheck still made the same complaint.

A number of places on the web recommended:

```
   ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 /lib/libpam.so.0
```

but that seemed to me like a grotesque hack, that would be sure
to land me in different trouble with different applications
farther down the road.

I tried a number of things with environment variables, including
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32`, but nothing
helped with the `db2prereqcheck`.

Someone I trust said to just go ahead with the install anyway.
So I did

```
   db2_install
```

(it was a remote headless system), and although the db2prereqcheck
that runs as part of the install complained, the install *did* work.

Sadly, db2start complained:

```
   sqllib/adm/db2start: error while loading shared libraries:
   libaio.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Someone I trusted recommended:

```
   apt-get install libaio1
```

which installed 64-bit libaio (prior to that my system only included
32-bit), after which I ended up with:

```
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1.0.1
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaio.so.1
```

After that, everything went fine.

Again, bottom line: I was missing 32-bit libpam and 64-bit libaio.

BTW, my system image already included packages `libstdc++6` and `lib32stdc++6`
-- something which a lot of folks seem to be missing in their environments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please separate question from answer.

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu server 14.04.02 (64 bit) I had to install the following packages before installing DB2 10.5:

- libx32stdc++6
- libpam0g:i386
- libaio1

Comment: Note: You might need to add packages for i386 architecture: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` then `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install libpam0g:i386`. Note for beginners getting DB2 installed: You install these packages using `apt-get`, the Ubuntu package manager. Ex: `apt-get install libx32stdc++6`. Use `sudo` to run these commands as root. (Otherwise you may not have enough access permissions.)

Answer (score 1):

You may have to run `ldconfig` after installing the i386 version of the pam library; DB2 searches the linker cache for it's dependencies, so if it's installed and there is an entry in `/etc/ld.so.cache.d/`, it should find it if `ldconfig` has been run.

Running something like `strace db2 connect to sample` will give you a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 /lib/libpam.so.0
```

This did the trick for me, despite the ugly hack.

`apt-get install libpam0g` said everything was installed and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

For the once trying to install DB2 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the missing package can be installed with the command:

`sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev:i386`

NOTE: the libpam0g-dev package is safer to install than the libpam0g package since it can be safely used only for development compilations and setup software to be installed.

NOTE2: the amd64 is around for more than 20 years now, maybe IBM will update DB2 to amd64 one of these days.

NOTE3: Thank you for this question, it save me hours of try and error